# Foreach loop on two SQL tables

Tags: sql, loops, join

I have two tables which are totally independent from each other, and I need to extract information from both of them and generate a CSV.

I'm doing this query:

```
SELECT NOM_FLUX, TYPE_CONTENU, DATE_DEPOT_GED 
FROM FLUX_GED 
WHERE TYPE_CONTENU = 'TEMPO_COURRIER_FSS' 
AND NOM_FLUX NOT LIKE 'PCC%'
```

With this result:

[image]

Then I'm doing a query from this result with the ID

Like This (on the first result)

```
SELECT ID, URL_RELATIVE, TYPE_CONTENU, NOM_ELEMENT 
FROM ELEMENT_GED 
WHERE ID IN (
    SELECT ID_ELEMENT 
    FROM SUIVI_GED 
    WHERE ID_FLUX IN (18682403)
)
```

With this result:

[image]

And here is the information from the SUIVI_GED table:

[image]

First I would like to do like a PowerShell foreach loop on every ID of my first query and then export the result of both query in a common csv.

I would like a result like that  for my csv:

```
NOM_FLUX;URL_RELATIVE;TYPE_CONTENU;NOM_ELEMENT
infoNomFlux;infoURL;infoType;infoNOM
```

Comment: Why loop? You can select all results in single query, no (slow) loops required.

Comment: ok but how? do you mean making my first query as a variable ?

Comment: Please add sample data from all tables (FLUX_GED, ELEMENT_GED & SUIVI_GED) with relation details if there any. Then add your expected output so that people understand your requirement better.

Comment: SQL is mostly *set* oriented. You describe what you want to do with sets of rows, and leave the database engine the job of working out whether to run loops, etc. It does take some getting used to if you've mostly worked with procedural languages previously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want `join`. A rather literal translation of your queries would be:

```
select 
    f.nom_flux, 
    f.type_contenu as type_contenu_flux, 
    f.date_depot_ged , 
    e.id, 
    e.url_relative, 
    e.type_contenu as type_contenu_element, 
    e.nom_element
from flux_ged f
inner join element_ged e
    on exists (select 1 from suivi_ged s where s.id_flux = f.id and e.id = s.id)
where 
    f.type_contenu = 'TEMPO_COURRIER_FSS' 
    and f.nom_flux not like 'PCC%'
```

Depending on your actual design, you might be able to flatten the `exists` condition as another join:

```
select 
    f.nom_flux, 
    f.type_contenu as type_contenu_flux, 
    f.date_depot_ged , 
    e.id, 
    e.url_relative, 
    e.type_contenu as type_contenu_element, 
    e.nom_element
from flux_ged f
inner join suivi_ged s on s.id_flux = f.id
inner join element_ged e on e.id = s.id
where 
    f.type_contenu = 'TEMPO_COURRIER_FSS' 
    and f.nom_flux not like 'PCC%'
```

Comment: ok I don't get everything on your query, I'd like to play it but it won't make any changes on my table? I' a real beginner and I don't want to breack somethig. Does the inner join change something or only read datas?

Comment: If I unsterdand you're trying to work around the different IDs but they are completely different, how could this work. Sorry I don't get it.

Comment: Does the inner join change something or only read datas? on your examples I mean

Comment: @HadrienBeaujean: this is a `select` statement, so it does not modify the data, it just reads it. Data modification statements are `insert` and `update`.

Comment: Sounds good but results are bad because it takes infos from the element id (e.id)
Documents names are the one of the element id

Comment: I've found what was wrong, had to change by inner join element_ged e on e.id = s.ID_ELEMENT